# What is the best format to use when creating a mail list for use in a Word 2007?

Tags: java, ms-word, office-2007, mailmerge

I'm writing a web app (Java) which allows users to select contacts. The contacts details can be downloaded (currently in CSV format) and used to perform a mail merge in Word 2007.

I would like to use a format which is a bit more 'robust' than CSV. Those of you in non-English areas will know the comma/semicolon problems!

Which format would you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer TSV (Tab Separated Values) for this sort of task.  I have never encountered a dataset containing literal tabs that were desired in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Not having much experience in "non-English" mail merges, what's wrong with exporting the contacts in xlsx format and using that as your datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reasons you have your user doing the mail-merge, you could consider moving all the work to the server side.  When the user selects the contacts and clicks ok, get the server to mail-merge and create the doc for the user and send it to them. [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) or [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) can provide this capability.  You could also allow the user to select different templates or if you are really generous, let the users upload their own.